# Android Facebook Keystore jks error

Tags: android, facebook, keystore, jks

I'm currently developping an app on Android that should support Facebook wall posting - nothing really exciting.

I used the official Facebook SDK and did everything as told. It works great on emulator.

My problem is when I try it on a real phone, I got the "java.security.KeyStoreException: KeyStore jks implementation not found" exception raised up.
It works on some phone, and not on the other ones. It's not related to Wifi or 3G connexion.

My guess (and it seems like a long shot) is that it doesn't work when the official Facebook application is installed/running.

Anyone already encountered this problem? How would you solve it? Is the interference between the two apps a possible cause? If not, what could be?

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Can you post your code showing how you setup your connection with facebook & your method for posting to the wall. I have an several app's that use facebook and have never recieved that error. Running your app with the facebook app installed/running actually makes things easier!